# How to remove directories using wildcards by reading a file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, batch, windows-command-prompt

**Batch file**

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do rd /s /q "%%f"
PAUSE
exit
```

**7profiledeletelist.txt**

```
C:\Users\1*
C:\Users\2*
C:\Users\3*
C:\Users\4*
C:\Users\5*
C:\Users\6*
C:\Users\7*
C:\Users\8*
C:\Users\9*
C:\Users\M*
C:\Users\T*
```

After reading the **7profiledeletelist.txt** file, the bat file can not delete anything.

If I remove `*` and write the exact name of the directory it is working well. I want to delete all folders starting with `M`, `T`, `1` until `9` in the Users directory.

How does `7profiledeletelist.txt` or the batch script need to change in order to make it work? Is there a mistaken code in the batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Q&A](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/17917-63-delete-folders-command-promote-wildcards), `rmdir` does not accept wildcards. However, issuing the following command:

`for /D %f in (1*) do rmdir %f /s /q`

removes all folders starting with `1`.

According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527877/batch-script-read-line-by-line) it is possible to read a file line by line using batch.

**rmdir_regex.bat**

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do (
  for /D %%f in (%%a) do rmdir %%f /s /q
)
```

Comment: Hi utrecht
Can we add an exception folders (not to be deleted) to this code?
For ex: Folder Name: is 235812 and 35284?

Comment: @serdar This means that the remove command needs to be encapsulated by an e.g. `if not` statement which is compared by e.g. `2*==235812`. This is hard to implement using batch to my opinion. However, PowerShell has more features than batch. Perhaps you could try to implement this using PowerShell and post the attempts in a new question if it does not work.